# Direct production between two arrays must have an array shape

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I wish to have a result such as: `{0,1,0,0}` after producing two vectors: `v1={1,0}` and `v2={0,1}`

I have tried by `TensorProduct` and `KroneckerProduct`, but they results in a matrix, not an array.

How can I receive the desired results!

Comment: `//Flatten` is ok.

Comment: `Flatten@ KroneckerProduct[v1, v2]`?

Comment: Yes you are right